# Pick random node from tree

Tags: java, data-structures, random, tree

I have a tree data structure, where each node can have multiple children. So there is not only a left and a right, but either less or even way more.
Now I want to pick a node from this tree randomly. For every node, I know how many children are connected to it. But how can I pick them in a random fashion, uniformly would be awesome. Any ideas? I found solutions for the case of only a left and a right child, but as I said, that is not really applicable here.

Comment: Are you only interested in picking *leaf* nodes, or would you want *branch* nodes to be picked as well?

Comment: actually, I'm interested in the arcs, but when I have the nodes, I will just choose the arc entering the node. So in other words, not only leaves, any node should be possible.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an observation that might be useful: suppose that you number all of the nodes in the tree in some fashion that makes it possible to efficiently look up the nth tree node for some arbitrary n.  If you can do this, then you can efficiently pick a random node by choosing a random node number, then going to that node.

One very simple way to do this would be to perform a DFS or other traversal of the tree and store all the nodes in a dynamic array.  You can then do O(1)-time random sampling by just indexing into the array.  However, this has O(n) memory overhead and is not good if the tree is constantly changing.

If the tree is rapidly changing, another way to number the nodes that decreases the time required to recalculate indices is the following.  Start off by numbering the root node 0.  Then, recursively number the nodes in the first subtree, then he second, etc.  Rather than storing this numbering explicitly, you can store it implicitly by having each tree node store the total number of nodes in the subtree rooted at that node.  That way, to look up the nth node in the tree, you can do the following:

1. If n = 0, return the root node.
2. Otherwise, set n = n - 1, then loop over the children of the current node one at a time from left to right as follows:

   1. Let k be the number of nodes in the subtree.
   2. If n < k, recursively find the nth node in this subtree.
   3. Otherwise, set n = n - k.

This approach runs very quickly if you have a relatively balanced tree with a reasonable branching factor, since you can rapidly discard parts of the tree that don't contain the nth element.

Using this approach, you get a very fast method (though not O(1)) for picking the nth element from the tree: choose a random index, then return the node at that index.  Additionally, this works even if nodes are added or removed from the tree.  Whenever a node is inserted, simply increment the count of all nodes on the path from the root to that node.  Whenever a node is deleted, decrement the count of all nodes on the path from the root to the deleted node.

This approach still uses O(n) overhead to store the counts, though.  For an O(1)-overhead algorithm that runs in linear time, look at @NPE's excellent solution based on reservoir sampling.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If uniform distribution is important, you could traverse the tree and use [reservoir sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling).

However, the time complexity of this is linear in the number of nodes.

Comment: Ok, I read reservoir sampling now, but I don't understand your idea. Let's say I'm at the root node of my tree, and I can see that it has 4 subtrees. The first one contains four more nodes, the second 3 the third 2 and the fourth 4 again. Ok, now what? I guess my n is the total number of nodes. But what is k? And when do I know that should choose a certain node?

Comment: @user1994555: If you just want one number, `k=1`. If you want, say, five numbers you can use `k=5`.

Comment: Ok, but how do I know that I should choose a node? You know, when does it stop?

Comment: @user1994555: You have traverse the entire tree. In the end you'll have `k` elements in the reservoir, which is your random sample.